# Как работает данный код, перевод из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    unsigned int value; int i;
    const unsigned int mask = 1 << 31;
    cout << "Введите целое число ";
    cin >> value;
    cout << "Двоичный вид: ";
    for (i = 1; i <= 32; i++)
    {
        putchar(mask & value ? '1' : '0');
        value <<= 1;
        if (i % 8 == 0) putchar(' ');
    }
}
```

Непонятно, каким образом это работает, маска принимает значение единицу, и двигается на 31 бит влево, для чего это?

Дальше идет цикл в котором сравнивается mask и value и value сдвигается каждую итерацию на один бит, зачем это нужно и как в итоге преобразуется в двоичный вид?

Comment: & - Это не сравнение, а оператор побитового И

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы вводите десятичное число, например, `value = 1234567890`. В памяти ЭВМ оно будет сразу представлено в двоичной форме в четырёх байтах переменной `value`. А именно, вот так: `0100 1001 1001 0110 0000 0010 1101 0010`.

Ваша программа шаг за шагом, начиная со старших битов, вычленяет по одному биту и выводит вам на экран, делая пробел через каждые 8 битов. Вот как это происходит.

У вас есть константа `mask = 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`. И ваше исходное значение `value=0100 1001 1001 0110 0000 0010 1101 0010`.

Шаг первый. Делаем побитовое И над этими числами:

```
   1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
&  0100 1001 1001 0110 0000 0010 1101 0010
------------------------------------------
=  000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Получили `0`. Ага, значит тернарный оператор `? :` вернёт вам символ `'0'`. Это мы вывели самый старший бит. Как вывести следующий по старшенству? Сдвигаем нашу `value` влево на 1 бит, и мы получим, что самый старший бит "отрезался" и предшествующий ему (который нам и нужен) встал на его место:

```
value = 1001 0011 0010 1100 0000 0101 1010 0100
```

Шаг второй: опять побитовое И:

```
   1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
&  1001 0011 0010 1100 0000 0101 1010 0100
------------------------------------------
=  100000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Хлоп! Получили НЕ ноль, а значит тернарный оператор `? :` вернёт `'1'`. Это второй по старшенству бит вашего числа.

Далее попробуйте сами :)

Дополнительно поясню только, что запись `value&mask` в данном случае эквивалентна записи `(value&mask)!=0`. То есть запись

```
putchar(mask & value ? '1' : '0');
```

Эквивалентна

```
if ((mask&value) != 0)  putchar('1');
else putchar('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Числа в компьютере хранятся уже и так в двоичном виде. Поэтому ничего никуда на самом деле переводить ну нужно. Этот код просто выводит каждую позицию двоичного представления числа. Сравнение с маской ( которая просто '1') требуется доя того, чтобы определить 1 или 0 в двоичном представлении на данной позиции:

1&1 = 1

1&0 = 0